# Logging into hotel Wi-Fi changes bash prompt?

Tags: wireless-networking, bash, unix, prompt

Since clicking on the “I agree” pop-up when logging into a hotel Wi-Fi, my `bash` prompt contains some kind of hash in it. The format is now:

```
<strange hash>:<working dir> <username>
```

What’s going on? Is this dangerous?

Comment: @Walrus the Cat can you provide a screnshot?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "strange hash" is your computer's current name, assigned by the hotel's DHCP server, and accepted by whatever DHCP client you're using. Run the `hostname` command to check if my guess is right.

To avoid this in the future:

- For *dhcpcd*, add `nohook hostname` to its configuration file. Also find the `option ...` settings, and make sure none of them list the `host_name` option.
- For *dhclient*, make sure the `request ...` settings do not list the `host-name` option.